# Volume of $ \Gamma=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3:\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le z\le \sqrt{2x^2+2y^2};x^2+y^2+z^2\le 3\} $

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I evaluated the volume of the set 
$$
\Gamma=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3:\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le z\le \sqrt{2x^2+2y^2};x^2+y^2+z^2\le 3\}
$$ by using the Pappu's centroid theorem, but I'm in trouble while evaluating the volume without using this theorem... can anybody help me? Thank you!

Comment: Do you know how to find volume in cylindrical coordinates or by the [washer method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disc_integration#Washer_method)?

Comment: I know a bit the cylindrical coordinates... but not a lot, how would you solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some helps. You say you know cylindrical coordinates, so I'll use that approach (though there are several other approaches such as washers, cylindrical shells, spherical coordinates, and Pappus's theorem).

[image]

As you can see from this side view (the eye on the plane $z=0$), the desired volume is between two cones and inside a sphere. We use cylindrical coordinates, and rewrite your inequalities using $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

$$r \le z \tag{1}$$
$$z \le \sqrt 2r \tag{2}$$
$$r^2+z^2 \le 3 \tag{3}$$

Inequality (1) implies that $z$ is nonnegative, so we need look only at the upper half of the diagram. We can rewrite those inequalities to put bounds on $r$:

$$r \ge \frac{z}{\sqrt 2} \qquad\text{from (2)} \tag{4}$$
$$r \le z \qquad\text{copying (1)} \tag{1}$$
$$r \le \sqrt{3-z^2} \qquad\text{from (3)} \tag{5}$$

The diagram shows that there are two regions. In the first region, the "wedge," $r$ is limited by the cones defined by inequalities $(4)$ and $(1)$. That region begins at the bottom at $z=0$ and stops at the top where the cone in $(1)$ intersects the sphere in $5$. We can find that value of $z$ be equating the two expressions:

$$z=\sqrt{3-z^2}$$

The solution to that is $z=\sqrt{\dfrac 32}$. So for $0\le z\le \sqrt{\dfrac 32}$ we have $\dfrac{z}{\sqrt 2}\le r\le z$. You can integrate with those
limits on $z$ and $r$, and $0\le \theta\le 2\pi$. This gives us the integral

$$V_1=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3/2}} \int_{z/\sqrt 2}^z \int_{0}^{2\pi} r\,d\theta\,dr\,dz$$

There is another region above that, the "ring" between the inner cone and the sphere. The bottom of that region is again $z=\sqrt{\dfrac 32}$. The top is the intersection of the cone defined by $(4)$ and the sphere defined by $(5)$. We find that upper value of $z$ again by equating expressions:

$$\frac{z}{\sqrt 2}=\sqrt{3-z^2}$$

The solution to that is $z=\sqrt 2$. So for $\sqrt{\dfrac 32}\le z\le \sqrt 2$ we have $\dfrac{z}{\sqrt 2}\le r\le \sqrt{3-z^2}$. Again, you can integrate with those limits on $z$ and $r$, and $0\le \theta\le 2\pi$. This gives us the integral

$$V_2=\int_{\sqrt{3/2}}^{\sqrt 2} \int_{z/\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt{3-z^2}} \int_{0}^{2\pi} r\,d\theta\,dr\,dz$$

Find those two volumes, add them, and you have your volume.

---

In a comment you asked if the same technique would work if both square roots were removed from the limiting inequalities. The answer is yes, but the limits on the integrals would change.

The resulting limits on $r$ would then be

$$r\le\sqrt z, \quad, r\ge\sqrt{\frac z2}, \quad, r\le\sqrt{3-z^20}$$

We again get two regions. The lower limit of the first is $z=0$. The upper limit is given by the combination of the first and last inequalities, which gives the upper limit

$$z=\frac{-1+\sqrt{13}}{2}$$

The second region's lower limit is the first's upper limit. The second's upper limit is given by the last two inequalities, which gives $z=\frac 32$. So your two integrals would be

$$V_1=\int_0^{(-1+\sqrt{13})/2}\int_{\sqrt{z/2}}^{\sqrt z}\int_0^{2\pi} r\,d\theta\,dr\,dz$$

$$V_2=\int_{(-1+\sqrt{13})/2}^{3/2}\int_{\sqrt{z/2}}^{\sqrt{3-z^2}}\int_0^{2\pi} r\,d\theta\,dr\,dz$$

Comment: Dear Professor Daulton, thank you very much for these hints, but I'm stuck when you say "you can integrate those limits on $z$ and $r$, and $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$", could you please show me how would you set those integrals? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @AlexejAlexandersen: I have added the integrals, but I'll leave it to you to evaluate them.

Comment: Thank you very much, so the total volume will be $V=2(V_1+V_2)$? Last question... why you wrote $0 \le z \le \sqrt{3/2}$, and then $\sqrt{3/2} \le z \le \sqrt{2}$? thank you..

Comment: @AlexejAlexandersen: I made a mistake. $z$ must be nonnegative, so the final volume is just $V_1+V_2$. I'll address your last question later when I have the time.

Comment: thank you very very much! I wish you a merry christmas and a happy new year to you and all your beloved

Comment: sorry, what if instead of two cones I have two paraboloids?

Comment: @AlexejAlexandersen; Then it would be a different problem with different inequalities. The same technique may still work, depending on the actual inequalities. Do you have specific ones in mind?

Comment: for example the same problem but without the square root

Comment: @AlexejAlexandersen: See the latest addition to my answer. You should be getting the idea by now. If you plan to do many of these problems, you should get a 3D grapher, such as [Geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/).

Answer (score 1):

In case it's of interest, this integral can be done in spherical coordinates. If $\theta$ denotes longitude and $\phi$ denotes colatitude, the solid $\Gamma$ is defined by
$$
0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi,\quad
\arctan(1/\sqrt{2}) \leq \phi \leq \pi/4,\quad
0 \leq \rho \leq 3;
$$
the volume of $\Gamma$ is therefore
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{\arctan(1/\sqrt{2})}^{\pi/4} \int_{0}^{3} \rho^{2} \sin\phi\, d\rho\, d\phi\, d\theta,
$$
or

> $18\pi\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$.

Comment: +1 for a good answer. If you added some details on the limits it would be better than mine! I didn't think to ask the OP about his knowledge of spherical coordinates, since that usually comes after cylindrical coordinates in the books that I have seen. But I still should have asked.

Comment: why $\arctan{\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}}\le\phi\le \pi/4$?

Comment: @AlexejAlexandersen: As you see in the diagram in my answer (the other one) and in my equations $(1)$ and $(4)$, the angle is bounded above by the line $r=z$ which has the slope $1$ and thus the angle of inclination $\operatorname{arctan}(1)=\frac{\pi}4$ and below by the line $r=\frac{z}{\sqrt 2}$ which has the slope $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ and thus the angle of inclination $\operatorname{arctan}(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2})$. Is that clear?